# Why wont this function run if there is letters in string x?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have this function to delete some `XML`. It runs with numbers only, but if there are letters in the string, it wont run, and if it's a mix(numbers and letters) I get an error. Can anyone help me?

The error I get is

> "System.Xml.XPath.XPathException:
>   '//Reservedele/Component[Varenummer=123eg]' has a illegal token.

```
//Udfør sletning af vare i map
protected void btnUdførSlet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string x = txtSletVare.Text;
    functions func = new functions();
    bool exists = func.checForMatch(txtSletVare.Text);

    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(Server.MapPath(map));
    //XmlNodeList nodes = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//Component[Varenummer=" + x + "]");
    XmlNode noteTodelete = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//Reservedele/Component[Varenummer=" + x + "]");

    if (exists != true)
    {
        lblFejlSletVare.Text = "Varenummeret findes ikke";
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            if (noteTodelete != null)
            {
                noteTodelete.ParentNode.RemoveChild(noteTodelete);
            }
            xmldoc.Save(Server.MapPath(map));
            sletImapBackUp();
        }
        catch { }


    }
}
```

Comment: Post a sample of the offending xml as well.

Answer (score 2):

If `x` contains only numbers, XPath interprets the value as numeric. If `x` also contains letters, it's interpreted as a string and needs to be quoted:

```
xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//Reservedele/Component[Varenummer='" + x + "']");
                                                            ^         ^
```

Comment: Obviously it will not work when x contains quotes, but that should be different duplicate

Comment: Generally it's best to avoid constructing XPath expressions using string concatenation, partly because of the problem of escaping special characters, and partly (related) because of the risk of injection attacks. Use an API that allows parameters to be set in the XPath expression. How to do this with Microsoft's XPath API isn't obvious, but I recall someone explaining how to do it with the XPathNavigator recently - can't find the question though.